# How to put text newar text at buttom op page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put few form, near to each other at bottom of the page.

Try to do that with css, but nothing work.

This is the css:

```
#Dcustomer,#Dorder,#admin{

    text-align:inline-block;

}

#Uadmin,#Uorder,#Ucustomer,#add
{
    float:right;
        vertical-align:10px;
}
```

This is example for the one of the form:

```
<form action="AdminControl.php" id="Uorder" method="POST">
   <h3><b><u>Update Order</b></u> </h3><br> 
   Order Number: <input type="text" name="Onumber"><br><br>
   Product Name: <input type="text" name="product_name"><br><br>
   Customer Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
   Customer Number: <input type="text" name="Cnumber"><br><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
   Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone"><br><br>
   Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity"><br><br>    
   <input type="submit" name="updateorder" value="Update">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see `#Dcustomer,#Dorder,#admin` in html and you should change  `text-align` to `display`

Comment: Consider rewriting your question as I do not understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Just uploaded in the main topic photo of the problem.just want all form to be at the same line,one near one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every screen may not be able to fit all in one line
So just float right or left every form (and reduce width if you want)
Link to example https://jsfiddle.net/vko4om7o/7/

```
    form {
        float: right;
        vertical-align: 10px;
        width: 25%;
    }
```

Increase size of frame for better visibility

Comment: I want it like the photo above.

Comment: Changed underline and spacing

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment you have syntax error in your css file.
You have to change `text-align` to `display` because `text-align` takes only `left, right, center` values.

Comment: you mean to write display-align:inline-block; or what?

Comment: `display: inline-block`

Comment: Create fiddle for this.

Comment: Here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/hmh8Lag6/1/ but it depends on window width, make your browser wider to see result.

Comment: Thanks a lot,but still as you say it not look so good when window max width.i put image of how it should be.pls help me with this

Comment: Open it in your brower and press ctrl with - then you will see how it looks on wider screen...

Comment: I do that already.in small size its look ok. I want it like the pic above, can you help me?